# vim auto indenting even after setting noai option

Tags: vim, putty, indentation, copy-paste

I am using vim 7.2 from putty terminal.
Even if I run `set noai` it seems vim still trying to indent code.
I am copying my code from Notepad++ to vim.
following is from Notepad++

[image]

and following what I got in vim:
[image]

I don't have any tab in my file.
As a workaround I am opening old vi run `set noai` paste save and open in vim again.
Any suggestion how to correct this behavior ?

Comment: why negative vote?

Comment: Probably because your question is not strictly Unix related. VIM runs just about any platform known to mankind.

Comment: @wzzrd: I thought its something to do with putty and unix terminal.

Comment: @wzzrd, really? I mean, there are a lot of unix related tools that run on non-unix systems as well. Including Windows versions of sed/grep for example ... And besides, what would be a better stackexchange site for vim questions?

Comment: Guys, guys, guys: I did not downvote this question. I am merely guessing what *might* be the reason for the downvote. As a matter of fact: I just upvoted it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the noai option. What you are experiencing, is a little trouble copy-pasting a load of text *with existing indents* to vim.

What I usually do (I have this 'problem' a lot), is bind F4 to invpaste and then, before I paste stuff into vim, hit that key. It makes the problem go away.

```
nnoremap <F4> :set invpaste paste?<CR>
```

Read more about this using

```
:help paste
```

inside vim

Comment: wow that worked. I will check :help paste :-). Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3):

`:set paste`
prevents the problem

`:set nopaste`
to undo the above

`:set pastetoggle=<F2>`
sets paste toggle key to F2